# Динамическое имя переменной

Tags: php

```
$field = 'mailbox';
$default_{$field} = 'abc';

print($default_{'mailbox'});//выводит abc
print($default_mailbox);//Ничего не выводит
```

P.S. Я уже "вспомнил" про массивы. Но что за такое происходит с именами переменных?

Comment: Интересно:))) Тоже такой же вопрос

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Может быть такой вариант Вам подойдет:

```
$field = 'mailbox';
${'default_'.$field} = 'abc';
echo $default_mailbox;
```

Но массивы действительно лучше. И без крайней необходимости пользоваться динамическими переменными не следует.

Comment: Подойдет вполне. Хотя я в итоге использовал просто массив(см вопрос).

    $default['mailbox'];

однако вопрос состоял именно почему нельзя часть имени представить так как представил я. Что происходит?

Comment: Нельзя потому-что разработчики ПоХаПе не предоставили такой возможности (кэп)

Comment: Интересно, а 

    ${'default_'.'mailbox'} 

превращается в `$default_mailbox` ?

Глядя на эти 2 примера (от @knes и @Barton) кажется, что просто в интерпретаторе какая-то ошибка при разборе и построении имени переменной.